# Join tool removes height of multiple objects

Tags: mesh, edges, loop

I am fairly new to Blender and I am struggling to join multiple ellipses with the Join tool in object mode.  I am trying to model a hatchet handle however with multiple lofted ellipses. In order to bridge the edge loops of the ellipses, I need to join the separate ellipses into a single object. However, every time I use the join tool it compresses the ellipses onto a single plane removing the height between the ellipses. How do I prevent the join tool from compressing the ellipses while still joining the ellipses into a single object? Below is the before and after of me using the join tool.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do the objects have modifiers?

Comment: You are joining to an object with zero scale on the Z axis

Comment: I do not think that the objects have modifiers and every time I try to join the objects it brings up a yellow alert that says "Active object final transform has one or more zero scales axes"

Comment: Thanks so much, Duarte, the z scale in the delta transform tab of each ellipse was zero and I had that collapsed so I couldn't see it. Changing that value to 1 for each ellipse fixed the problem. Thanks!